# Preventing installation conflicts with SageMath

Tags: python, installation, sage, lean

I just got a new MacBook Air (M1, macOS 12.3.1) and installed Sage from the dmg and it's working beautifully. But now I'd like to install some other things and not ruin Sage the way I did on my old computer. Here's the things I would like to do now in order of importance, if it can’t all be done:

1. Run Python in Visual Studio Code.
2. Run Python in Eclipse.
3. Get and use Anaconda.
4. Run Lean in Visual Studio Code.

How do I do this? If I install Python again naively, won’t it interfere with Sage? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this question is answerable in its current form. If you have concrete information on exactly what went wrong, we might be able to help. It should definitely be possible to have all these things present without them interfering with one another.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Many thanks for writing. My recollection of the problem was that the Sage launcher failed to launch the Jupyter notebook. That is, the launcher showed up but clicking to open the notebook on the launcher did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The Sage-macOS installer is designed to provide
a batteries-included Sage.

The resulting Sage is isolated from the rest of the system.

Installing other software is unlikely to interfere with it.